# Using fonts from winfonts package with report document class

Tags: fonts, texlive, linux

The `winfonts` package (around since 2006) is said to provide the following fonts for LaTeX<sub>2e</sub>.

```
Arial           Franklin Gothic     Tahoma           
Comic Sans      Georgia             Times
Courier New     Palatino Linotype   Verdana
```

I have been looking through several documents for using new fonts in LaTeX<sub>2e</sub> with `NFSS` or *New Font Selection Scheme*:

```
cfgguide.pdf
clsguide.pdf
fntguide.pdf
fontinstallationguide.pdf
fontname.pdf
```

as well as in some books:

```
Kopka H., Daly P.W.
A Guide To LaTeX: Document Preparation for Beginners and Advanced Users
3rd ed, 1999

Lamport L.
LaTeX: A Document Preparation System: User's Guide and Reference Manual
2nd ed, 1994

Mittelbach Fr., Goossens M.
The LaTeX Companion
2nd ed, 2004
```

and it looks intricated to use those fonts. I especially require plain LaTeX<sub>2e</sub> (neither `XeTeX` nor `ConTeXt` - also, the driver must be `PDFLATEX`, so the part with `dvips` would not do) and `report` document class, somewhere along these lines **[EDITED:MWE#3]**:

```
\RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc}
\RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\RequirePackage{winfonts}
%\input{t1verdana.fd}
%\input{ts1verdana.fd}
%\input{winfonts.sty}
\RequirePackage{newunicodechar}

\documentclass{report}

\fontfamily{verdana}\selectfont
\renewcommand\rmdefault        {verdana}
%\renewcommand\ttdefault        {verdana}
%\renewcommand\sfdefault        {verdana}
%\renewcommand\seriesdefault    {verdana}
%\renewcommand\mddefault        {verdana}
%\renewcommand\bfdefault        {verdana}
%\renewcommand\shapedefault     {verdana}
%\renewcommand\updefault        {verdana}
%\renewcommand\itdefault        {verdana}
%\renewcommand\scdefault        {N/A}
%\renewcommand\sldefault        {verdana}
\renewcommand\familydefault    {\rmdefault}

\title{\LaTeX~package 'winfonts' MWE}
\author{Glita Sebastian}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\chapter{MWE}

\section{one}

\begin{itemize}
    \item \textrm{normal} % Default
    \item \textrm{roman} % Roman
    \item \texttt{typewriter} % typewriter style / Monospaced
    \item \textit{italics} % Italic
    \item \textsf{sans--serif} % Sans Serif
    \item \textbf{bold} % Bold
    \item \textsl{slanted} % Slanted
    %\item \textsc{small caps} % all capital letters / Small Caps
    \item \textup{upright} % Upright
    \item \textmd{md} % Medium
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

**[EDITED:MWE]**

The output works, but the log gives **[EDITED:not with MWE#3 - solved]**:

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `T1/rmdefault/verdana/verdana' undefined
[1]LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `T1/rmdefault/verdana/verdana' in size <20> not 
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `TS1/rmdefault/verdana/verdana' undefined
[1]LaTeX Font Warning: Size substitutions with differences
LaTeX Font Warning: Some font shapes were not available, defaults substituted.
```

Under Linux, with `texlive-2013` distribution, the list of `winfonts` package has:

```
/etc/texmf/updmap.d/50winfonts.cfg
/usr/share/texmf-dist/ttf2pk/winfonts_ttf2tfm.map
/usr/share/texmf-site/fonts/map/pdftex/winfonts/winfonts.map

/usr/share/texmf-site/fonts/vf/monotype/
timesttf/mtmri8t.vf
timesttf/mtmri8c.vf
timesttf/mtmr8t.vf
timesttf/mtmr8c.vf
timesttf/mtmbi8t.vf
timesttf/mtmbi8c.vf
timesttf/mtmb8t.vf
timesttf/mtmb8c.vf
impact/micr8t.vf
impact/micr8c.vf
courierttf/mcrr8t.vf
courierttf/mcrr8c.vf
courierttf/mcrb8t.vf
courierttf/mcrb8c.vf
arial/malri8t.vf
arial/malri8c.vf
arial/malr8t.vf
arial/malr8c.vf
arial/malbi8t.vf
arial/malbi8c.vf
arial/malb8t.vf
arial/malb8c.vf

/usr/share/texmf-site/fonts/vf/microsft/
verdana/jvnri8t.vf
verdana/jvnri8c.vf
verdana/jvnr8t.vf
verdana/jvnr8c.vf
verdana/jvnbi8t.vf
verdana/jvnbi8c.vf
verdana/jvnb8t.vf
verdana/jvnb8c.vf

/usr/share/texmf-site/fonts/tfm/monotype/
timesttf/rmtmri8t.tfm
timesttf/rmtmri8c.tfm
timesttf/rmtmr8t.tfm
timesttf/rmtmr8c.tfm
timesttf/rmtmbi8t.tfm
timesttf/rmtmbi8c.tfm
timesttf/rmtmb8t.tfm
timesttf/rmtmb8c.tfm
timesttf/mtmri8t.tfm
timesttf/mtmri8c.tfm
timesttf/mtmr8t.tfm
timesttf/mtmr8c.tfm
timesttf/mtmbi8t.tfm
timesttf/mtmbi8c.tfm
timesttf/mtmb8t.tfm
timesttf/mtmb8c.tfm
impact/rmicr8t.tfm
impact/rmicr8c.tfm
impact/micr8t.tfm
impact/micr8c.tfm
courierttf/rmcrr8t.tfm
courierttf/rmcrr8c.tfm
courierttf/rmcrb8t.tfm
courierttf/rmcrb8c.tfm
courierttf/mcrr8t.tfm
courierttf/mcrr8c.tfm
courierttf/mcrb8t.tfm
courierttf/mcrb8c.tfm
arial/rmalri8t.tfm
arial/rmalri8c.tfm
arial/rmalr8t.tfm
arial/rmalr8c.tfm
arial/rmalc8t.tfm
arial/rmalc8c.tfm
arial/rmalbi8t.tfm
arial/rmalbi8c.tfm
arial/rmalb8t.tfm
arial/rmalb8c.tfm
arial/malri8t.tfm
arial/malri8c.tfm
arial/malr8t.tfm
arial/malr8c.tfm
arial/malbi8t.tfm
arial/malbi8c.tfm
arial/malb8t.tfm
arial/malb8c.tfm

/usr/share/texmf-site/fonts/tfm/microsft/
verdana/rjvnri8t.tfm
verdana/rjvnri8c.tfm
verdana/rjvnr8t.tfm
verdana/rjvnr8c.tfm
verdana/rjvnbi8t.tfm
verdana/rjvnbi8c.tfm
verdana/rjvnb8t.tfm
verdana/rjvnb8c.tfm
verdana/jvnri8t.tfm
verdana/jvnri8c.tfm
verdana/jvnr8t.tfm
verdana/jvnr8c.tfm
verdana/jvnbi8t.tfm
verdana/jvnbi8c.tfm
verdana/jvnb8t.tfm
verdana/jvnb8c.tfm

/usr/share/texmf-site/fonts/enc/dvips/winfonts/
ts1-winfonts.enc
ts1-winfonts-pala.enc
ts1-winfonts-pala-pk.enc
tex256cj-pala.enc
tex256cj-pala-pk.enc
tex256-pala.enc
tex256-pala-pk.enc

/usr/share/texmf-site/fonts/afm/monotype/
timesttf/rmtmri8t.afm
timesttf/rmtmri8c.afm
timesttf/rmtmr8t.afm
timesttf/rmtmr8c.afm
timesttf/rmtmbi8t.afm
timesttf/rmtmbi8c.afm
timesttf/rmtmb8t.afm
timesttf/rmtmb8c.afm
impact/rmicr8t.afm
impact/rmicr8c.afm
courierttf/rmcrr8t.afm
courierttf/rmcrr8c.afm
courierttf/rmcrb8t.afm
courierttf/rmcrb8c.afm
arial/rmalri8t.afm
arial/rmalri8c.afm
arial/rmalr8t.afm
arial/rmalr8c.afm
arial/rmalc8t.afm
arial/rmalc8c.afm
arial/rmalbi8t.afm
arial/rmalbi8c.afm
arial/rmalb8t.afm
arial/rmalb8c.afm

/usr/share/texmf-site/fonts/afm/microsft/verdana/
rjvnri8t.afm
rjvnri8c.afm
rjvnr8t.afm
rjvnr8c.afm
rjvnbi8t.afm
rjvnbi8c.afm
rjvnb8t.afm
rjvnb8c.afm

/usr/share/texmf-site/fonts/truetype/public/msttcorefonts/
verdanaz.ttf
verdana.ttf
verdanai.ttf
verdanab.ttf
times.ttf
timesi.ttf
timesbi.ttf
timesbd.ttf
impact.ttf
cour.ttf
couri.ttf
courbi.ttf
courbd.ttf
ariblk.ttf
arial.ttf
ariali.ttf
arialbi.ttf
arialbd.ttf

/usr/share/texmf-site/tex/latex/winfonts/
ts1verdana.fd
ts1times-ttf.fd
ts1courier-ttf.fd
ts1arial.fd
t1verdana.fd
t1times-ttf.fd
t1courier-ttf.fd
t1arial.fd
winpifont.sty
wingding.sty
winfonts.sty
windings.sty
windingbats.sty
```

The content of `"/usr/share/texmf-dist/ttf2pk/winfonts_ttf2tfm.map"` is:

```
% Entries for the winfonts bundle 

rmalr8t arial.ttf Encoding=tex256.enc 
rmalri8t ariali.ttf Encoding=tex256.enc 
rmalb8t arialbd.ttf Encoding=tex256.enc 
rmalbi8t arialbi.ttf Encoding=tex256.enc 

rmalc8t arialbd.ttf Encoding=tex256.enc 
rjo5r8t comic.ttf Encoding=tex256.enc 
rjo5b8t comicbd.ttf Encoding=tex256.enc 
rmcrr8t cour.ttf Encoding=tex256.enc 
rmcrb8t courbd.ttf Encoding=tex256.enc 
rifgr8t framd.ttf Encoding=tex256.enc 
rifgri8t framdit.ttf Encoding=tex256.enc 
rjgir8t georgia.ttf Encoding=tex256.enc 
rjgiri8t georgiai.ttf Encoding=tex256.enc 
rjgib8t georgiab.ttf Encoding=tex256.enc 
rjgibi8t georgiaz.ttf Encoding=tex256.enc 
rmicr8t impact.ttf Encoding=tex256.enc 
rjybr8t sylfaen.ttf Encoding=tex256.enc 
rjthr8t tahoma.ttf Encoding=tex256.enc 
rjthb8t tahomabd.ttf Encoding=tex256.enc 
rmtmr8t times.ttf Encoding=tex256.enc 
rmtmri8t timesi.ttf Encoding=tex256.enc 
rmtmb8t timesbd.ttf Encoding=tex256.enc 
rmtmbi8t timesbi.ttf Encoding=tex256.enc 
rjtrr8t trebuc.ttf Encoding=tex256.enc 
rjtrri8t trebucit.ttf Encoding=tex256.enc 
rjtrb8t trebucbd.ttf Encoding=tex256.enc 
rjtrbi8t trebucbi.ttf Encoding=tex256.enc 
rjvnr8t verdana.ttf Encoding=tex256.enc 
rjvnri8t verdanai.ttf Encoding=tex256.enc 
rjvnb8t verdanab.ttf Encoding=tex256.enc 
rjvnbi8t verdanaz.ttf Encoding=tex256.enc 
rmalr8c arial.ttf Encoding=ts1-winfonts.enc 
rmalri8c ariali.ttf Encoding=ts1-winfonts.enc 
rmalb8c arialbd.ttf Encoding=ts1-winfonts.enc 
rmalbi8c arialbi.ttf Encoding=ts1-winfonts.enc 
rmalc8c arialbd.ttf Encoding=ts1-winfonts.enc 
rjo5r8c comic.ttf Encoding=ts1-winfonts.enc 
rjo5b8c comicbd.ttf Encoding=ts1-winfonts.enc 
rmcrr8c cour.ttf Encoding=ts1-winfonts.enc 
rmcrb8c courbd.ttf Encoding=ts1-winfonts.enc 
rifgr8c framd.ttf Encoding=ts1-winfonts.enc 
rifgri8c framdit.ttf Encoding=ts1-winfonts.enc 
rjgir8c georgia.ttf Encoding=ts1-winfonts.enc 
rjgiri8c georgiai.ttf Encoding=ts1-winfonts.enc 
rjgib8c georgiab.ttf Encoding=ts1-winfonts.enc 
rjgibi8c georgiaz.ttf Encoding=ts1-winfonts.enc 
rmicr8c impact.ttf Encoding=ts1-winfonts.enc 
rjybr8c sylfaen.ttf Encoding=ts1-winfonts.enc 
rjthr8c tahoma.ttf Encoding=ts1-winfonts.enc 
rjthb8c tahomabd.ttf Encoding=ts1-winfonts.enc 
rmtmr8c times.ttf Encoding=ts1-winfonts.enc 
rmtmri8c timesi.ttf Encoding=ts1-winfonts.enc 
rmtmb8c timesbd.ttf Encoding=ts1-winfonts.enc 
rmtmbi8c timesbi.ttf Encoding=ts1-winfonts.enc 
rjtrr8c trebuc.ttf Encoding=ts1-winfonts.enc 
rjtrri8c trebucit.ttf Encoding=ts1-winfonts.enc 
rjtrb8c trebucbd.ttf Encoding=ts1-winfonts.enc 
rjtrbi8c trebucbi.ttf Encoding=ts1-winfonts.enc 
rjvnr8c verdana.ttf Encoding=ts1-winfonts.enc 
rjvnri8c verdanai.ttf Encoding=ts1-winfonts.enc 
rjvnb8c verdanab.ttf Encoding=ts1-winfonts.enc 
rjvnbi8c verdanaz.ttf Encoding=ts1-winfonts.enc 
rlplr8t pala.ttf Encoding=tex256-pala-pk.enc 
rlplri8t palai.ttf Encoding=tex256-pala-pk.enc 
rlplb8t palab.ttf Encoding=tex256-pala-pk.enc 
rlplbi8t palabi.ttf Encoding=tex256-pala-pk.enc 
rlplrc8t pala.ttf Encoding=tex256cj-pala-pk.enc 
rlplric8t palai.ttf Encoding=tex256cj-pala-pk.enc 
rlplbc8t palab.ttf Encoding=tex256cj-pala-pk.enc 
rlplbic8t palabi.ttf Encoding=tex256cj-pala-pk.enc 
rlplr8c pala.ttf Encoding=ts1-winfonts-pala-pk.enc 
rlplri8c palai.ttf Encoding=ts1-winfonts-pala-pk.enc 
rlplb8c palab.ttf Encoding=ts1-winfonts-pala-pk.enc 
rlplbi8c palabi.ttf Encoding=ts1-winfonts-pala-pk.enc 
wingding wingding.ttf Encoding=wingding.enc PS=Only
webdings webdings.ttf Encoding=webdings.enc PS=Only
```

The content of `"/usr/share/texmf-site/fonts/map/pdftex/winfonts/winfonts.map"`:

```
rmalr8t ArialMT "T1Encoding ReEncodeFont" <[tex256.enc <arial.ttf
rmalri8t Arial-ItalicMT "T1Encoding ReEncodeFont" <[tex256.enc <ariali.ttf
rmalb8t Arial-BoldMT "T1Encoding ReEncodeFont" <[tex256.enc <arialbd.ttf
rmalbi8t Arial-BoldItalicMT "T1Encoding ReEncodeFont" <[tex256.enc <arialbi.ttf
rmalc8t Arial-BoldMT "T1Encoding ReEncodeFont" <[tex256.enc <arialbd.ttf
rjo5r8t ComicSansMS "T1Encoding ReEncodeFont" <[tex256.enc <comic.ttf
rjo5b8t ComicSansMS-Bold "T1Encoding ReEncodeFont" <[tex256.enc <comicbd.ttf
rmcrr8t CourierNewPSMT "T1Encoding ReEncodeFont" <[tex256.enc <cour.ttf
rmcrb8t CourierNewPS-BoldMT "T1Encoding ReEncodeFont" <[tex256.enc <courbd.ttf
rifgr8t FranklinGothic-Medium "T1Encoding ReEncodeFont" <[tex256.enc <framd.ttf
rifgri8t FranklinGothic-MediumItalic "T1Encoding ReEncodeFont" <[tex256.enc <framdit.ttf
rjgir8t Georgia "T1Encoding ReEncodeFont" <[tex256.enc <georgia.ttf
rjgiri8t Georgia-Italic "T1Encoding ReEncodeFont" <[tex256.enc <georgiai.ttf
rjgib8t Georgia-Bold "T1Encoding ReEncodeFont" <[tex256.enc <georgiab.ttf
rjgibi8t Georgia-BoldItalic "T1Encoding ReEncodeFont" <[tex256.enc <georgiaz.ttf
rmicr8t Impact "T1Encoding ReEncodeFont" <[tex256.enc <impact.ttf
rjybr8t Sylfaen "T1Encoding ReEncodeFont" <[tex256.enc <sylfaen.ttf
rjthr8t Tahoma "T1Encoding ReEncodeFont" <[tex256.enc <tahoma.ttf
rjthb8t Tahoma-Bold "T1Encoding ReEncodeFont" <[tex256.enc <tahomabd.ttf
rmtmr8t TimesNewRomanPSMT "T1Encoding ReEncodeFont" <[tex256.enc <times.ttf
rmtmri8t TimesNewRomanPS-ItalicMT "T1Encoding ReEncodeFont" <[tex256.enc <timesi.ttf
rmtmb8t TimesNewRomanPS-BoldMT "T1Encoding ReEncodeFont" <[tex256.enc <timesbd.ttf
rmtmbi8t TimesNewRomanPS-BoldItalicMT "T1Encoding ReEncodeFont" <[tex256.enc <timesbi.ttf
rjtrr8t TrebuchetMS "T1Encoding ReEncodeFont" <[tex256.enc <trebuc.ttf
rjtrri8t TrebuchetMS-Italic "T1Encoding ReEncodeFont" <[tex256.enc <trebucit.ttf
rjtrb8t TrebuchetMS-Bold "T1Encoding ReEncodeFont" <[tex256.enc <trebucbd.ttf
rjtrbi8t Trebuchet-BoldItalic "T1Encoding ReEncodeFont" <[tex256.enc <trebucbi.ttf
rjvnr8t Verdana "T1Encoding ReEncodeFont" <[tex256.enc <verdana.ttf
rjvnri8t Verdana-Italic "T1Encoding ReEncodeFont" <[tex256.enc <verdanai.ttf
rjvnb8t Verdana-Bold "T1Encoding ReEncodeFont" <[tex256.enc <verdanab.ttf
rjvnbi8t Verdana-BoldItalic "T1Encoding ReEncodeFont" <[tex256.enc <verdanaz.ttf
rmalr8c ArialMT "ts1-winfonts ReEncodeFont" <[ts1-winfonts.enc <arial.ttf
rmalri8c Arial-ItalicMT "ts1-winfonts ReEncodeFont" <[ts1-winfonts.enc <ariali.ttf
rmalb8c Arial-BoldMT "ts1-winfonts ReEncodeFont" <[ts1-winfonts.enc <arialbd.ttf
rmalbi8c Arial-BoldItalicMT "ts1-winfonts ReEncodeFont" <[ts1-winfonts.enc <arialbi.ttf
rmalc8c Arial-BoldMT "ts1-winfonts ReEncodeFont" <[ts1-winfonts.enc <arialbd.ttf
rjo5r8c ComicSansMS "ts1-winfonts ReEncodeFont" <[ts1-winfonts.enc <comic.ttf
rjo5b8c ComicSansMS-Bold "ts1-winfonts ReEncodeFont" <[ts1-winfonts.enc <comicbd.ttf
rmcrr8c CourierNewPSMT "ts1-winfonts ReEncodeFont" <[ts1-winfonts.enc <cour.ttf
rmcrb8c CourierNewPS-BoldMT "ts1-winfonts ReEncodeFont" <[ts1-winfonts.enc <courbd.ttf
rifgr8c FranklinGothic-Medium "ts1-winfonts ReEncodeFont" <[ts1-winfonts.enc <framd.ttf
rifgri8c FranklinGothic-MediumItalic "ts1-winfonts ReEncodeFont" <[ts1-winfonts.enc <framdit.ttf
rjgir8c Georgia "ts1-winfonts ReEncodeFont" <[ts1-winfonts.enc <georgia.ttf
rjgiri8c Georgia-Italic "ts1-winfonts ReEncodeFont" <[ts1-winfonts.enc <georgiai.ttf
rjgib8c Georgia-Bold "ts1-winfonts ReEncodeFont" <[ts1-winfonts.enc <georgiab.ttf
rjgibi8c Georgia-BoldItalic "ts1-winfonts ReEncodeFont" <[ts1-winfonts.enc <georgiaz.ttf
rmicr8c Impact "ts1-winfonts ReEncodeFont" <[ts1-winfonts.enc <impact.ttf
rjybr8c Sylfaen "ts1-winfonts ReEncodeFont" <[ts1-winfonts.enc <sylfaen.ttf
rjthr8c Tahoma "ts1-winfonts ReEncodeFont" <[ts1-winfonts.enc <tahoma.ttf
rjthb8c Tahoma-Bold "ts1-winfonts ReEncodeFont" <[ts1-winfonts.enc <tahomabd.ttf
rmtmr8c TimesNewRomanPSMT "ts1-winfonts ReEncodeFont" <[ts1-winfonts.enc <times.ttf
rmtmri8c TimesNewRomanPS-ItalicMT "ts1-winfonts ReEncodeFont" <[ts1-winfonts.enc <timesi.ttf
rmtmb8c TimesNewRomanPS-BoldMT "ts1-winfonts ReEncodeFont" <[ts1-winfonts.enc <timesbd.ttf
rmtmbi8c TimesNewRomanPS-BoldItalicMT "ts1-winfonts ReEncodeFont" <[ts1-winfonts.enc <timesbi.ttf
rjtrr8c TrebuchetMS "ts1-winfonts ReEncodeFont" <[ts1-winfonts.enc <trebuc.ttf
rjtrri8c TrebuchetMS-Italic "ts1-winfonts ReEncodeFont" <[ts1-winfonts.enc <trebucit.ttf
rjtrb8c TrebuchetMS-Bold "ts1-winfonts ReEncodeFont" <[ts1-winfonts.enc <trebucbd.ttf
rjtrbi8c Trebuchet-BoldItalic "ts1-winfonts ReEncodeFont" <[ts1-winfonts.enc <trebucbi.ttf
rjvnr8c Verdana "ts1-winfonts ReEncodeFont" <[ts1-winfonts.enc <verdana.ttf
rjvnri8c Verdana-Italic "ts1-winfonts ReEncodeFont" <[ts1-winfonts.enc <verdanai.ttf
rjvnb8c Verdana-Bold "ts1-winfonts ReEncodeFont" <[ts1-winfonts.enc <verdanab.ttf
rjvnbi8c Verdana-BoldItalic "ts1-winfonts ReEncodeFont" <[ts1-winfonts.enc <verdanaz.ttf
rlplr8t PalatinoLinotype-Roman "T1Encoding-pala ReEncodeFont" <[tex256-pala.enc <pala.ttf
rlplri8t PalatinoLinotype-Italic "T1Encoding-pala ReEncodeFont" <[tex256-pala.enc <palai.ttf
rlplb8t PalatinoLinotype-Bold "T1Encoding-pala ReEncodeFont" <[tex256-pala.enc <palab.ttf
rlplbi8t PalatinoLinotype-BoldItalic "T1Encoding-pala ReEncodeFont" <[tex256-pala.enc <palabi.ttf
rlplrc8t PalatinoLinotype-Roman "T1Encodingcj-pala ReEncodeFont" <[tex256cj-pala.enc <pala.ttf
rlplric8t PalatinoLinotype-Italic "T1Encodingcj-pala ReEncodeFont" <[tex256cj-pala.enc <palai.ttf
rlplbc8t PalatinoLinotype-Bold "T1Encodingcj-pala ReEncodeFont" <[tex256cj-pala.enc <palab.ttf
rlplbic8t PalatinoLinotype-BoldItalic "T1Encodingcj-pala ReEncodeFont" <[tex256cj-pala.enc <palabi.ttf
rlplr8c PalatinoLinotype-Roman "ts1-winfonts-pala ReEncodeFont" <[ts1-winfonts-pala.enc <pala.ttf
rlplri8c PalatinoLinotype-Italic "ts1-winfonts-pala ReEncodeFont" <[ts1-winfonts-pala.enc <palai.ttf
rlplb8c PalatinoLinotype-Bold "ts1-winfonts-pala ReEncodeFont" <[ts1-winfonts-pala.enc <palab.ttf
rlplbi8c PalatinoLinotype-BoldItalic "ts1-winfonts-pala ReEncodeFont" <[ts1-winfonts-pala.enc <palabi.ttf
rwingding Wingdings-Regular "wingdingencoding ReEncodeFont" <[wingding.enc <wingding.ttf
rwebdings Webdings "webdingsencoding ReEncodeFont" <[webdings.enc <webdings.ttf
```

AFAIK, the LaTeX<sub>2e</sub> `NFSS` gives steps how to generate some of the files from the actual font files via other files, and it seems this to have already been done by the `winfonts` packager.

I use also the `newunicodechar` package and have defined **many** `utf-8` "*unicodemathsymbols*" as `\newcommandx`s to issue corresponding LaTeX math macros: there is also the trouble of using `winfonts` in math mode, too.

Appreciate any insight on how to use the fonts the easiest/fastest way, and where is more to do from my part, I gladly accept your help with this.

Thank s.

I would work this out alone, but perhaps I need get jump-started.

**[EDITED]**

Just to check the `winfonts.map` is found by `updmap-sys`:

```
user@localhost ~ less /var/lib/texmf/web2c/updmap.log
...
Scanning for Map entries
...
/usr/share/texmf-site/fonts/map/pdftex/winfonts/winfonts.map

         [150 files]
...
/usr/share/texmf-site/fonts/map/pdftex/winfonts/winfonts.map:
rjvnb8c
rjvnb8t
rjvnbi8c
rjvnbi8t
rjvnr8c
rjvnr8t
rjvnri8c
rjvnri8t
rmalb8c
rmalb8t
rmalbi8c
rmalbi8t
rmalc8c
rmalc8t
rmalr8c
rmalr8t
rmalri8c
rmalri8t
rmcrb8c
rmcrb8t
rmcrr8c
rmcrr8t
rmicr8c
rmicr8t
rmtmb8c
rmtmb8t
rmtmbi8c
rmtmbi8t
rmtmr8c
rmtmr8t
rmtmri8c
rmtmri8t
...
```

And `/var/lib/texmf/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map` contains lines like:

rjvnri8t Verdana-Italic " T1Encoding ReEncodeFont " <[tex256.enc

Comment: It is rather unclear what is actually your problem. If everything is installed correctly and if you enabled the winfonts.map it should work already (but not in math, these are not math fonts).

Comment: Okay, I edited - added an MWE and checked `updmap-sys`. My *problem* is that I figured I must do something tremendous [in the MWE] - besides a correct installation of winfonts - that one is supposed to with NFSS and new fonts. Because the log shows clearly that all I did is not yet enough. Something related with those codes 'rjvnri8t' etc.

Comment: You are redefining too much. Don't change \updefault etc but only rmdefault to v verdana.

Comment: Did you try reading the documentation e.g. section 3.1 'How to select a family?'? Or you could use the included `.sty` file which will mean you hardly even need read the instructions.

Comment: thanks, the only redefinitions in MWE#2 left are for  rm/tt/sf fonts; sc (smallcaps) was not available.

Comment: You don't need `\fontfamily...\selectfont` - just renew the definition of the roman family as you do on the next line.